# как правильно прописать ip сервера на роутере

Tags: сервер, сеть, ip

Добрый день я ищу мануал по подключению сервера в интернет точнее как правильно задать статический ip . Где именно на роутере прописать локальный ip сервера чтобы при отправлении запроса на мой статический ip или домен роутер перенаправлял трафик в мой сервер .
P-660HW-T1 v3 модель роутера . Я прописал данные в Static Route и Dynamic DNS но ничего не работает порты 80 443 открыты
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Порты закрыты, а адрес то какой у вас теперь? Проверьте сервисом типа 2ip.ru, а порты еще пробросить надо как бы..

Answer (score 0):

Впешите в поиск Google 192.168.0.1 , войдите в систему, клацните в меню на "Быстрая настройка" или "Сеть"->"WAN"->"Тип подключения"="Статический ip" и вводите все данные которые вам предоставил или предоставит провайдер.

Comment: я все прописоваю  но выдает ошибку ERROR: Duplicate to a VPI/VCI ! а у меня по дефолту идут  те что провайдер предоставил